# Linux ALSA Driver using channel count 3

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, alsa

I'm running my ALSA Driver on Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit, 3.16.0-30-generic Kernel.

Hardware is proprietary, hence can't provide much details.

Following is the existing driver implementation:

1. Driver is provided channel_count as input via module parameter. (Due to requirements need to provide ch count via module parameter)
2. Driver fills alsa snd_pcm_hardware structure as playback->channels_min = channel_count & for playback->channels_max = channel_count; Same values for capture side.
3. Hardware is configured for clocks based on channel_count, and driver registers successfully with ALSA layer
4. aplay/arecord works fine for channel_count = 1/2/4
5. During aplay/arecord, In driver when "runtime->channels" value is checked it reflects the channel_count configured, which sounds correct to me. Record data matches with played, since it's a loop back test.

But when i use channel_count  = 3,
Both aplay or arecord reports "Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available"!! for a wave file with channel_count '3'

ex:
Playing WAVE './xxx.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 3

ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable

aplay: set_params:1204: Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available

---

With Following changes I was able to move ahead a bit:

Method1:

1. Driver is provided channel_count '3' as input via module parameter
2. Modified Driver to fill snd_pcm_hardware structure as payback->channels_min = 2 & playback->channels_min = 3; Similar values for capture path
3. aplay/arecord reports as 'channel count not available', though the wave file in use has 3 channels

ex: aplay -D hw:CARD=xxx,DEV=0 ./xxx.wav
Playing WAVE './xxx.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 3

aplay: set_params:1239: Channels count non available

4. Tried aplay/arecord with plughw, and aplay/arecord moved ahead

modprobe my_driver.ko Channel=3

arecord -D plughw:CARD=xxx,DEV=0 -d 3 -f S16_LE -r 48000 -c 3 ./xxx_rec0.wav

aplay -D plughw:CARD=xxx,DEV=0 ./xxx.wav

Recording WAVE './xxx_rec0.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 3

Playing WAVE './xxx.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 3

End of Test

5. During aplay/arecord, In driver when "runtime->channels" value is checked, it returns value 2!!! But played wavefile has ch count 3...
6. When data in recorded file is checked its all silence

---

Method2:

1. Driver is provided channel_count '3' as input via module parameter
2. Modified Driver to fill snd_pcm_hardware structure as playback->channels_min = 3 & playback->channels_min = 4; Similar values for capture path
3. aplay/arecord reports as 'channel count not available', though the wave file in use has 3 channels
4. Tried aplay/arecord with plughw, and aplay/arecord moved ahead
5. During aplay/arecord, In driver when "runtime->channels" value is checked it returns value 4!!! But played wavefile has ch count 3...
6. When data in recorded file is checked its all silence

So from above observations, the runtime->channels is either 2 or 4, but never 3 channels was used by alsa stack though requested.
When used Plughw, alsa is converting data to run under 2 or 4 channel.

Can anyone help why am I unable to use channel count 3?
Will provide more information if needed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show all the actual values of the `snd_pcm_hardware` structure. (And this question belongs on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response.

Will place the question in stackoverflow.

If you can help further, here is what you requested for.

define DEFAULT_PERIOD_SIZE                      (4096)

define DEFAULT_NO_OF_PERIODS                    (1024)

static struct snd_pcm_hardware xxx_playback =

{

```
.info                   = SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP |
                          SNDRV_PCM_INFO_INTERLEAVED |
                          SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP_VALID |
                          SNDRV_PCM_INFO_SYNC_START,
.formats                = SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S16_LE,
.rates                  = (SNDRV_PCM_RATE_8000 | \
                           SNDRV_PCM_RATE_16000 | \
                           SNDRV_PCM_RATE_48000 | \
                           SNDRV_PCM_RATE_96000),
.rate_min               = 8000,
.rate_max               = 96000,
.channels_min           = 1,
.channels_max           = 1,
.buffer_bytes_max       = (DEFAULT_PERIOD_SIZE * DEFAULT_NO_OF_PERIODS),
.period_bytes_min       = DEFAULT_PERIOD_SIZE,
.period_bytes_max       = DEFAULT_PERIOD_SIZE,
.periods_min            = DEFAULT_NO_OF_PERIODS,
.periods_max            = DEFAULT_NO_OF_PERIODS,
```

};

Similar values for captures side snd_pcm_hardware structure.

Please, note that the following below values will be replaced in playback open entry point,based on the current audio test configuration:
(user provides audio format, audio rate, ch count via module parameters as inputs to the driver, which are refilled in snd_pcm_hardware structure)

xxx_playback.formats,

xxx_playback.rates,

xxx_playback.rate_min, xxx_playback.rate_max,

xxx_playback.channels_min, xxx_playback.channels_max

(Similarly values replaced in snd_pcm_hardware structure on capture side)

Comment: Solution provided at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304697/linux-alsa-driver-using-channel-count-3